# Events for resuming an app

Tags: windows-phone-7, events

Are there any events being fired on the Windows Phone 7 (Mango) when you:

a) stay in a view for so long that the screen goes to sleep, and you unlock your phone and return to the app?

b) tap the windows button and then the back-button to resume the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes when you stay on a page long enough the OnNavigatedTo event for that particular page is fired.
2. When you resume an app the Aplication_Activated event on the page App.xaml.cs is fired as well as the OnNavigatedTo event of the page is fired.

Comment: Thanks :-) Are there any resume-specific events though?

Comment: Nope only Application_Activated is there, you can save that data which you want to persist after resuming the application in the Application_Deactivated method